# How can I get the array to show the previous list of array content before the next input?

Tags: c++

I need the user input to be saved into my array and then output the array before the user inputs the next time. I have been moving things around different ways but cannot seem to get them to perform properly. I tried to cut down the code to the two functions I am having issues with.

```
void PlayGame()
{

const int HighestNum = 50;
const int LowestNum = 1;
int RandomNumber = LowestNum + rand() % HighestNum; //set for better random results


cout << "Guess the random number between " << LowestNum << " and " << HighestNum << "!\n\n";

const int attempts = 15;// limits the attempts to guess the random number to 15
int Guess [attempts] = {};



    cout << "Enter your guess " << endl;

    for (int count = 0; count < attempts; count++)
    {

        cin >> Guess[count];


    int z = RandomNumber, y = Guess[count], r;

    r = reviewGuess (z,y);//calling the function that determines the results

        switch (r)//switch statement for function results, letting the user know if they matched the number, if the number is higher, or lower
        {
        case 0:
            cout << "You Win!!" << endl;
            cout << "\n";
            cin.get();
            return;                
        case 1:
            cout << "The number is higher than your guess" << endl;
            break;
        case -1:    
            cout << "The number is lower than your guess" <<endl;
            break;
        }

    if (count == 15)
    {
        cout << "Sorry, no guesses remain. The random number was... " << RandomNumber << "!";//so the user can see the random number at the end of their attempts
        cout << "\n";
        cin.get();
        Again();
    }
}
return;
}

 int DisplayGuess(int member[])
{
 for(int i = 0; i < 15; ++i)
    cout << "\nGuess " << i + 1 << ": " << member[i];
 cout << endl;
 return;
}
```

Comment: Why is your indentation so haphazard? What possible reason could you have for that?

Comment: The function `DisplayGuess` declares a return type of `int`, yet no value is returned. Why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this inside your loop

```
if(count > 0)
{
    for (int j= 0; j < count; j++)
    {
       cout<<Guess[j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call DisplayGuess() in the first line of the for loop. Since the first you time you call it your array is empty, it shouldn't output anything.

So,

```
 for (int count = 0; count < attempts; count++)
{
     DisplayGuess(Guess[count]);
     cin >> Guess[count];

     int z = RandomNumber, y = Guess[count], r;
     r = reviewGuess (z,y);//calling the function that determines the
     results
     . . . . . .
```